# How can I measure the effect of more than one continuous variable on one dichotomous variable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have one dichotomous variable as "success" which I valued as pass (1) and fail (0). I have  3 continuous variables as "study hour", "attendance" and "classroom participation". I want to investigate how these 3 continuous variables affect success. And also which one affects more. Something like this:
Success    hour        attendace          participation
    0        17             8                   6
    1        28             14                  9
    0         8             1                   2 
    1         35            18                  13

I have about 50 participants. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A multivariable probit/logit model ?

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but how can I apply it in spss? I think my participant size is not enough for different types of regression.

Comment: I am not familiar with spss so I cannot help you with the code, I only know stata and R.

Your sample size is indeed very small for solid results, but I am afraid it would be for every method and software

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, so now it seems I need to increase my sample size.

Comment: Well if you can it would be great. It is rarely easy though. You can start running some regressions, just be careful with how assertive you are with what you obtain !

Comment: I really love regression but due to my field of study (psycholinguistics) a single data acquisition process takes more than 10 minutes and data analysis part is really exhausting. Reaching 100 and more participants is quite rare in instructional settings. But if 100 is enough for a logistic regression, maybe I can push for it.

Comment: I am not familiar with your field of study as I come from economics and econometrics. What I suggested is the now standard method for your type of problem. 
I cannot give a precise threshold that would be the number of observations you need to have a valid estimation. The more the best. Below 30 is very very difficult, above 200 would start to be nice.

Comment: Hi Aerandal, I have taken into account what you advised recently and now decided to change my research design. If you advise me again it would be great. Here it is: I have two groups: Experimental and control groups. I want to compare lingustic developments of these groups in 5 month period depending on continuous data which was taken in 3 identical time periods.

Comment: Both of the groups will be tested if they develop significantly in terms of 3 or more continous variables (such as grade or reading time)and how they differ from each other. Can I use two way repeated measures ANOVA? I want to know which group developed better. Thanks alot.